# Terminal command for determining specs

Tags: macos

I realise that you can easily determine a macs specs by examining the 'About this Mac' function on the desktop. But I would like to do it through the terminal if it's possible to. So how do you go about doing it? If there are any comprehensive resources you can recommend point me to em!

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for is the `system_profiler` command.

Create `plist` containing system information for all `SPDataTypes`:

```
system_profiler -xml
```

Create `plist` containing information for specific `SPDataType`:

```
system_profiler -xml SPHardwareRAIDDataType
```

List of `SPDataTypes`:

```
SPParallelATADataType
SPApplicationsDataType
SPAudioDataType
SPBluetoothDataType
SPCardReaderDataType
SPComponentDataType
SPDeveloperToolsDataType
SPDiagnosticsDataType
SPDiscBurningDataType
SPEthernetDataType
SPExtensionsDataType
SPFibreChannelDataType
SPFireWireDataType
SPFirewallDataType
SPFontsDataType
SPFrameworksDataType
SPDisplaysDataType
SPHardwareDataType
SPHardwareRAIDDataType
SPNetworkLocationDataType
SPLogsDataType
SPManagedClientDataType
SPMemoryDataType
SPModemDataType
SPNetworkDataType
SPPCIDataType
SPParallelSCSIDataType
SPPowerDataType
SPPrefPaneDataType
SPPrintersSoftwareDataType
SPPrintersDataType
SPConfigurationProfileDataType
SPSASDataType
SPSerialATADataType
SPSoftwareDataType
SPStartupItemDataType
SPSyncServicesDataType
SPThunderboltDataType
SPUSBDataType
SPUniversalAccessDataType
SPNetworkVolumeDataType
SPWWANDataType
SPAirPortDataType
```

For further details how to use `system_profiler` run:

```
man system_profiler
```

Comment: Great answer - highly recommended. The exact command for what i was looking was                                                            system_profiler -SPHardwareDataType. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As @Anne posted, `system_profiler` is useful, but if you need more details, such as CPU model number, family, stepping, features (ex. SSSE3), try

```
sysctl
```

Each line of output contains the full hierarchy of categories so you can grep down the results to what you're looking for, ex. to see CPU details:

```
sysctl | grep machdep.cpu
```

View the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html) online or in the terminal:

```
man sysctl
```